# Webrequest Proxy Timeout Value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, proxy

I am trying to setup Proxy timeout value, so that if proxy fails to work after 10 seconds, it should cancel the request. How can i do so in HTTPWebRequest or WebRequest?

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://testserver:80/");
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
webRequest.Proxy = webProxy;
webRequest.Timeout = 5000;
```

Is it Timeout property only? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Regards

Comment: How are you using the `webProxy` instance? MSDN says the timeout only applies to synchronous calls made to `GetResponse`.

Comment: yes, after that i call GetResponse method. Thats just the partial code i use.

Comment: Based on the code you have posted and what you have said it should work. However, can't really help more without more code.